# Kernel decomposition of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\longrightarrow W$ be a linear map between vector spaces over the same field. I know that
$$V/\operatorname{Ker}(T)\cong\operatorname{Im}(T)$$
I want to deduce a relation of the form
$$V=\operatorname{Ker}(T)\oplus V'$$
where $V'$ is a subspace of $V$, isomorphic to the quotient $V/\operatorname{Ker}(T)$.
Is it possible? If yes, how can I prove it? If not, how can it be corrected?

Comment: Are these *finite dimensional* linear spaces?

Comment: Regarding to Don's comment, you just need to show that $V=Ker + Im$. Note that we need to show that $Ker\cap Im=\{0\}$.

Comment: @BabakS. Why do you think that should work? Kernel and image lie in different spaces...

Comment: @BabakS. We won't generally get $\;\ker T\cap\text{Im}\,T=0\;$ ...The problem, even in the finite case, is slightly messier...very slightly, though. Yet the OP hasn't said anything...

Comment: @DonAntonio not necessarily

Comment: @DonAntonio: I, honestly and dangerously, mixed this with the fact wich we have for a space vector $V$ and fot two subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a basis for $\text{Ker}(T)$ and extend to a basis of $V$. This works even for infinite dimensional spaces as long as you accept the Axiom of Choice. The difference between the extended basis and the original basis generates a space $V'$ which satisfies $V = \text{Ker}(T) \oplus V'$. The projection $V \to V'$ induces an isomorphism $V/\text{Ker}(T) \cong V'$ by the usual isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with finite-dimensional vector spaces one possible way of finding $V'$ is this: take a basis of $V$.  Let $m={\rm dim\, Im}(T)$. Evaluate $T$ on the basis elements. Find $m$ vectors among the basis elements such that their images remain linearly independent. $V'$ will be the subspace of $V$ spanned by them.